# How do I embed a .js video with html?

Tags: javascript, html, video, embed, dotnetnuke

I'm using DNN and trying to embed a video from an external site.  I had a working code before, but didn't save it because it was 1 line and thought it would be basic enough for me to remember.  The vendor has given us this code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return(false);" 
   rel="videoGUID=13cd1ac61aba5s4e92SbecaR0a18bbe36111&"
   style="display:block;width:1280px;height:740px"
   id="13cd1ac61aba5s4e92SbecaR0a18bbe36111" width="1280"
   height="740">Foundation Birthday Updated
</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://360.sorensonmedia.com/13cd1ac61aba5s4e92SbecaR0a18bbe36111/embedv2.js"></script>
```

I'm trying to embed this in an HTML module.  Again, this was working before.  the `<script>` tag gets stripped in the HTML module.  I believe I just used the .js link and put it in an object or iframe tag to get it to embed.  Any ideas?

Quicktime or installation of other video plug-ins isn't an option.

Comment: Those viewing, have made edit to formatting so code and tagged words become visible. Waiting for review to approve edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply visit the url http://360.sorensonmedia.com/13cd1ac61aba5s4e92SbecaR0a18bbe36111/embedv2.js in chrome you will see the following page (of course, with Flash enabled, the applet will play.

[image: screenshot of js file]

This is because whoever set up the server at Sorenson Media is serving javascript files with the mime-type of `text/html`. When insert it in the `src` attribute of a script tag, the browser will infer that it is javascript despite that.

However, when it is visited as a webpage the web browser obeys the mime-type and attempts to display it. However, this isn't an HTML document! Chrome guesses that it should be like this:

```html
<head></head><body>var embedCode = "<object style="outline:none;" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://static.cdn.360.sorensonmedia.com/1/flash/flowplayer-3.2.2.swf" id="videoPlayer_api" title="Adobe Flash Player">";
embedCode += "<param name="movie" value="http://static.cdn.360.sorensonmedia.com/1/flash/flowplayer-3.2.2.swf">";
embedCode += "<param value="transparent" name="wmode">";
embedCode += "<param value="true" name="allowfullscreen">";
embedCode += "<param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess">";
embedCode += "<param value="high" name="quality">";
embedCode += "<param value="false" name="cachebusting">";
embedCode += "<param value="#000000" name="bgcolor">";
embedCode += "<param value="config=&quot;;
embedCode += &quot;{&quot;play&quot;:{&quot;replayLabel&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;opacity&quot;:0},&quot;playlist&quot;:[{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;http://cdnimages.sorensonmedia.com/a6d2ad22-a413-4443-8cff-8dc210da7fcd/d18…quot;13cd1ac61aba5s4e92SbecaR0a18bbe36111&quot;,&quot;autoPlay&quot;:false, &quot;fileVersionId&quot;:&quot;5d231001b55b0945a5xaf4dd54cfe2999567&quot;,&quot;captionUrl&quot;:&quot;&quot;},{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;http://cdnimages.sorensonmedia.com/a6d2ad22-a413-4443-8cff-8dc210da7fcd/d18…screen&quot;:{&quot;bottom&quot;:10},&quot;onLoad&quot;:&quot;&quot;}&quot;;
embedCode += &quot;" name="flashvars">";
embedCode += "</object>";


var VideoEmbed = function (publishing_id, embed_code) {

  this.publishing_id  = publishing_id;
  this.embed_code     = embed_code;
  this.container      = document.getElementById(this.publishing_id);

  /**
   * Determines the installed (and enabled) version of flash.
   * @returns [major, minor]
   */
  function get_flash_version() {
    var fo, ver,
        RE = /(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)[^\d]*(\d*)/;

    try {
      ver = navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"].description.slice(16);
    } catch(e) {

      try  {
        fo = new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.7");
        ver = fo &amp;&amp; fo.GetVariable("$version");

      } catch(err) {
        try  {
          fo = new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.6");
          ver = fo &amp;&amp; fo.GetVariable("$version");
        } catch(err2) { }
      }
    }

    ver = RE.exec(ver);
    return ver ? [ver[1], ver[3]] : [0, 0];
  }

  /**
   * Inserts a flash embed code in a provided DOM element.
   */
  function insert_embed_code() {
    // embed the video
    try {
      this.container.innerHTML = this.embed_code;
    } catch (err) {}

    // for embedding video in WinXP Firefox
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Windows") != -1) {
      if (/Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        this.container.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          return false;
        }, false);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Inserts a prompt instructing user to install flash in a provided DOM
   * element.
   */
  function prompt_to_install_flash() {

    // set href attribute of <a> container and remove onclick handler
    try {
      this.container.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash');
      this.container.removeAttribute('onclick');
      this.container.onclick = null; // for IE7
    } catch (err) { }

    // display message to install flash
    this.container.innerHTML = '' +
      '<p style="text-align: center; ' +
                'margin: 1.5em 3em; ' +
                'padding: 1em; ' +
                'border: 1px solid #ccc; ' +
                'border-radius: 6px; ' +
                'background-color: #ddd; ' +
                'color: #3494d1; ' +
                'text-shadow: none;">' +
        'To view this video, please install the latest version of Flash.' +
        '<br><br>' +
        '<img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" '="" +="" 'style="outline: none; border: 0 none;">' +
      '</p>';
  }

  /**
   * If a user has flash installed, this embeds a video.  Otherwise, it
   * instructs the user to install flash.
   */
  this.display = function() {

    // determine flash version
    var flash_version = get_flash_version.call(this);

    // TODO: allow for specifying version as argument
    if (flash_version[0] &gt; 10 || flash_version[0] == 10 &amp;&amp; flash_version[1] &gt;= 1) {
      insert_embed_code.call(this);
    }

    // appropriate flash version not installed
    else {
      prompt_to_install_flash.call(this);
    }

  }

};


var embed = new VideoEmbed("13cd1ac61aba5s4e92SbecaR0a18bbe36111", embedCode);
embed.display();
</a></body>
```

This guess sort of works, but as you can see there is a lot of gunk displayed that shouldn't be.

**In addition, this is relying on the server being misconfigured and the browser making just the right guesses when interpreting javascript as html. DON'T USE IT!**

If you read the javascript code, you will see that most of it is just a fallback for if Flash isn't available. You might be able to hack together an html version without the fallbacks, but it will be easily broken if Sorenson Media gets their act together.

Your best option if to figure out how to include javascript in this HTML module.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with a pretty simple solution.  I put the HTML module into "basic text editor" and the render mode set to "raw.  This keeps the `<script>` tag.  No the solution I previously had, but it works.